# Pandas: convert last columns to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert the last two columns to numeric. I don't want to refer to those columns by label, as the structure of the dataframe might change. I always want to update the last two columns.

**Source Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'b': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'c': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'd': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'e': ['1','2','3','4','5']
})


df

    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5
```

Actually, I want to make the following dynamic (always last two columns instead of hardcoded 'd' and 'e')

```
df[['d', 'e']] = df[['d', 'e']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `df['d','e'] = df['d','e'].astype(int)`

Comment: No, I want to replace 'd' and 'e' by a dynamic reference to always the last two columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.columns[-2:]` gives you the names of the last two columns. so you can try:

```
df[df.columns[:-2]] = df[df.columns[:-2]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Or you can use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:, -2:] = df.iloc[:, -2:].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: i think the first one with df.columns does not work as it creates a copy and not a reference. Second works, though. Thanks

Comment: @Lorenz There's a typo in the first: `[-2:]` not `[:-2]`. It should work as expected, since it is exactly the same as your line of code.